# Jquery UI: How to change select option back to default?

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I am using jquery ui to create my select option menu from this examples

[Jquery selectmenu examples](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu)

Is there away to to change the select option back to the default value after the user has selected either option1, option2 or option 3 and the value was done outputting/ ie once the event ss completed, it should change back to "choose one..".

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){       

            // please note that option.event is always passed as a string, so do not test for true or 1 with if (options.value)
            // see this issue for more information http://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/issues#issue/12
            var speedD_first = $('select#speedD_first').selectmenu();       
           // alert(speedD_first[0]);


           // var selVal=$('select#speedD_first').selectmenu("value");
            //alert(selVal);
            $('select').selectmenu({
                change: function(e, object){
                    alert(object.value);
                }
            });

            //$('select').show();
        });     
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select#speedD_first").change(function() {
              var selVal=$("select#speedD_first").val();
            //  alert(selVal);
            });

        });
    </script>

<fieldset>
            <label for="speedD_first">Disabled and selected first option by HTML</label>
            <select id="speedD_first">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one...</option>
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            <select>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: i dont know much about selectmenu widget,but couldnt you also set value to "Choose one..." option (like option0) and then change it with: $('#speedD_first option[value="option0"]').attr("selected", "selected");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery UI documentation](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu) talks about a `refresh` method, but in my testing, it does not seem to work. This is likely due to `selectmenu` being a non-final jQuery UI component that is still in its planning phase. Instead, calling `.selectmenu()` again seems work and it is mentioned as the way to change state in the [development version documentation](http://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu).

NOTE: I am using the latest development version ([JS](http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js) / [CSS](http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectmenu.css)) of the plug-in.

```
$('select').selectmenu({
    change: function (e) {

        // Do something
        alert('Just to pause');

        // Rever to original value and reset
        $(this).val(0);
        $(this).selectmenu();
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Zex/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of the original select, then use `refresh` method for the widget

Run this in console on demo page:

```
$('#number').val(3).selectmenu('refresh');
```

Thus set the value of your default option or empty string if it has no value